# Python How can I use global variables in a class

Tags: python

the code:

```
class ceshi():
    def one(self):
        global a
        a = "i m a"

    def two(self):
        print(a)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ceshi().two()
```

error message:
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Didn't I define "a"? why the error message is 'name "a" is not defind'

Comment: *Didn't I define "a"* no, you didn't. `a = something` will be defining `a`. Since you want it to be global it should be outside the class scope.

Comment: you never called one() method so the global variable does not exist. It would exist if you create it outside class first

Comment: The problem is not that `a` isn't out of the class. You can perfectly leave it within `def one()` and be global, but you also need to actually make a call to function `one()`, which you never do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never actually define `a`. Just because you have it within function `one` does not mean that this function will be called.

You should either move `a` out of the class scope:

```
 a = "i m a"
 class ceshi():
    def one(self):
        # some other code

    def two(self):
        print(a)
```

or make a call to `one()` before calling `two()`, in order to define `a`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ceshi().one()
    ceshi().two()
```

Answer (score -1):

"a" is only defined inside `def one()`, so you should declare it outside the method scope and later on define its value inside `def one()` if that's what you want to do. You could just leave it inside `def one()` but if the method isn't called, it still won't work.

So your code should look like:

```
class ceshi():
    global a
    def one(self):       
        a = "i m a"

    def two(self):
        print(a)
```

Comment: Why do you think that `global a` should be moved out of the method into the class?

Comment: I think OP is getting this error because he didn't call the method one() before calling two(), so moving it out of the method would fix it?

Comment: The OP not calling `one()` *is* the problem. Moving the global statement does not help that. Global statements go in a region of local scope to indicate that a referenced variable is global instead of local.

Comment: I see, I thought it would print None if the variable is declared but not defined. Should I delete the answer when it's incorrect?

Comment: Whether you delete it is up to you. The [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73732477/3890632) has been provided by another user.